# Friendly URL pointing to a CSS file is being interpreted as HTML and not as CSS

Tags: php, css

I'm working with friendly urls and, one of my routers is to access CSS and JS files. Just like: "localhost/css/cssFileName".

And the route treats this url like this:

```
require(".".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."views".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."res".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."css".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."css".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nome.".css");
```

Where $nome is the variable pointing to "cssFileName".

Ok. When I access the url, the CSS content is displayed!

But when I try to link it in a page, just like this:

I get this in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I think I know what is going on! The browser tries to read the url result as a CSS but the header is for HTML. Isn't it?

But, how can I solve this? I mean, how can I make this url result to be interpretated as CSS?

Comment: May I ask why you're having friendly URL's to your CSS and JS files? And also why you're loading them through PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Content-Type HTTP header is missing. Prepend your `require` line with the following:

```php
header('content-type: text/css');
```